# Does System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator use the TPM's RNG?

Tags: .net, security, random

Does System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator use the TPM's RNG if a TPM is installed and active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RandomNumberGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator(v=vs.110).aspx) class is just an abstract class creating a standard way of interacting with (i.e. programming against) a random number generator. If you want to use a particular random number generator (RNG), such as that from a TPM, you will need to consult the documentation and/or libraries that came with the TPM.

If the TPM provides a Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP), instantiating a [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) with the a [CspParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) argument allows you to specify the CSP (and thus the TPM-provided RNG) to use. For example:

```
// Find in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider Types
int providerType; 
// Find in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider
string providerName;

CspParameters cspParameters = new CspParameters(providerType, providerName);
RNGCryptoServiceProvder = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters);
```

Comment: The TPM itself doesn't, but which (if any) of the OS-shipped CSPs in Win7/8/8.1 will use the TPM?

Comment: @KristoferA Unfortunately, I do not know. I have seen some documentation that says that some CSPs work but not which TPMs work with CSPs. Most of my lower level CSP programming has been against smartcard readers, which tend to create their own CSPs.

Comment: Thanks. After digging around a bit, I found a driver package that also included 4 CSPs for the (Infineon) TPM.